# MS Word: Automatic connector arrows to indented sub-paragraphs possible?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to find a way for Word to automatically create flowchart style connector arrows like in the image below to indented subparagraphs. Any solutions?

[image: Example]

Comment: Automatic insertion requires VBA.

Comment: Word does not have such connector arrows for text but only for graphical objects (shapes & textboxes). I am unsure whether it has elbow connectors. PowerPoint might.